# Regex To find words with missing letters

Tags: regex

I am trying to match words with up to two missing letters with regex. For example, if the word of interest is 'hello', I want to match the following strings:

```
hello
hell
helo
hllo
ello
hel
heo
elo
llo
```

I can use the regex `h?e?l?l?o?` to match these, but this will also match 0, 1, and 2 letter strings as well. How can I require the match to be 3-5 characters long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a look ahead to check for 3-5 of those characters:

```
    (?=[hello]{3,5})h?e?l?l?o?
```

Note that this will find a match like in a string like `help` since `help` contains `hel`. If you want to stp that you can check word boundaries or ends of string depending on your situation. If you want to match the ends of the sting add a `^` to the beginning and a `$` to the end. If you want to check word boundaries add `\b` to both ends.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will work `((?=.{3,})h?e?l?l?o?)` - your regex, with "at least 3 characters" added on.

You probably want this to only match whole words as well (not the start of something like "hellow"), so add `\b` to the start and the end: `\b((?=.{3,})h?e?l?l?o?)\b`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
[hello]{3,5}
```

Comment: but that would match `olleh` or `hhhhh` - i don't think OP wants that. ps corrected minor error: 3,4 -> 3,5